# Remove Standard Styles from Ribbon (HTML Site Column)

Tags: 2013, site-column

According to this [link](https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx) we can add some custom styles to the ribbon for HTML Fields. Is it possible to remove the standard ones?
(I especially want to remove Heading 1-4 and Heading 1-4 alternate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove them with one simple CSS line:

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Paragraph\
{display:none;}
```

credits to this [blog](http://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/Blog/default/Marz-2012/SharePoint-2010-Branding-Standard-Markup-Styles) (German)

For more details on the Default Server Ribbon Customization Locations see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx)